# Angular/Phonegap App: Cannot Display Image Using File URI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm using Phonegap's getPicture() method to save the File URI to an image, which I then try to display in an img element, but can't. Here's more detail.

1. I have a view with the following image element: `<img id='myImage' ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" style='width:320px;display:block'/>`
2. When I push a button in the view it calls the getPhoto() method in the view's controllers. Here's the code for the controller:

   ```
   .controller('captureController',function($scope,$rootScope,$state,$document){

   $scope.getPhoto = function() {
   navigator.camera.getPicture(
       captureSuccess,
       captureError,
       {
        quality:5,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG
       }
   );  
   }


   function captureSuccess(imageURI) {
       var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

       $rootScope.imageSrc=imageURI
       $rootScope.$apply()
       alert($rootScope.imageSrc)


   }


   function captureError(error) {
   var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
   alert('there was an error')
   }

   })
   ```
3. When I take a picture, the resulting alert returns the path to the photo (file:///var/mobile/Applications//tmp/cdv_photo_069.png), but the photo doesn't appear in the image element.

I've verified that photos are in the phone's tmp directory,and I've also tried replacing the image element's ng-src attribute with src="file:///....cdv_photo.png". The image element is still not rendering the picture.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.